# Apache mod_rewrite problems

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have a project with the following in the .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

I have two files in a directory `test.txt` & `test.php`

I can access `/path/to/folder/test.txt` but not `/path/to/folder/text.php`.

What am I missing? This configuration did work before on a different server.

Comment: Please append the webservers [error log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) and the [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog). You should always include debug information in the question, without it, it's more like guessing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```